# Is signed magnitude and two's compliment of a binary number the same when given a positive decimal value?

Tags: binary, decimal

Is signed magnitude and two's compliment of a binary number the same when given a positive decimal value?

for example the value +29 (decimal)
signed magnitude is 00011101
two's compliment is 00011101

for example the value -29 (decimal)
signed magnitude is 10011101
two's compliment is 11100011

is this true for all positive decimal numbers?

Comment: In a word: yes. Ditto for 1's complement.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement): `In two's-complement representation, positive numbers are simply represented as themselves, and negative numbers are represented by the two's complement of their absolute value;`

Answer (score 0):

**Positive Always True.**

---

### **but Negative also can be true✔️.**

---

**Whenever all bits are zeros except the last two bits from left.**

---

*For example*: *If I gave you  `1100` in binary it will be equal in each notation,
it will be **`-4`** in **Sign & Magnitude** and **Two's Compliment**.*